# Sunspot doesn't recognize email extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Today I have been facing the following problem with Sunspot,. It was working previously but now mysteriously stopped.

When I am searching by email and I input the name of the person for example `mushos32@yahoo.gr`
it doesn't give me any results, althought when I write `mushos32@` or any other combination before the `@` it gives me the result of this person(`mushso32@y` does not give me results). I will link my code below:

```
UserController index
 @users = []
unless params[:search].nil? || params[:search].strip.empty?
  @search = User.search do
    fulltext params[:search]
  end
  @users = @search.results
 end
@users
```

UserModel

```
 searchable do
 text :email
 end
```

User/Index

```
 <%= form_tag users_path, :method => :get do %>
<p>
  <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search" , :email => nil  %>

</p>

<% if @users.empty? %>
    <p>Your search did not return any results. </p>
<% else %>
<% for user in @users %>
    <tr>

      <td><%= link_to user.name, user %> <%= link_to user.surname, user %></td>
      <%= hidden_field_tag :direction, params[:direction] %>
      <%= hidden_field_tag :sort, params[:sort] %>
      <td><%= image_tag user.photo.url(:thumb) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to "Connect", friendships_path(:friend_id => user), :method => :post %></td>
    </tr>
<%end%>
```

Comment: Have you reindexed your data? If not please try `bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:reindex` and see whether it was just an old-index issue

Comment: I tried that still it does not work properly, whenever i make fullsearch by email it does not show the correct answer whenever i put the email extention

Comment: and you did restart your server for any case, right?

Comment: yes i restarted aswell